# Create hyperlink from html table row to open record on a new page

Tags: php, html, mysql

To begin with I know very little PHP and no java/javascript or jquery. I have created an html table populated from mysql database.  It is for a call log.  I am wanting to click on either a `<td>` or `<tr>` to open the corresponding record in a new page to be viewed in more detail.  I have thought about putting the call_id value in a hidden column to be used in a variable somehow, but don't know where to go from there or if that is anywhere near the correct way to accomplish this.

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: `<a href="corresponding_record?id=$x">click me</a>`, basically

Comment: Well, `id={$x}`, rather.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're creating the table doing something like this,

```
$results = some_mysql_query;
foreach ($results as $index => $array) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $array['RecordNumber'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $array['CallerName'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $array['Time'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $array['Duration'];
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then you can add in a link by doing something like this:

```
$results = some_mysql_query;
foreach ($results as $index => $array) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "<a href='recordInfo.php?record='" . $array['RecordNumber'] . "'>" . $array['RecordNumber'] . "</a>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "$array['CallerName'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $array['Time'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $array['Duration'];
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

NOTE the use of single-quotes, ', inside the double-quotes - and the '" / "' surrounding the variable.

Alternatively, your echo with the link could look like this:

```
            echo "<a href='recordInfo.php?record='{$array['RecordNumber']}'>{$array['RecordNumber']}</a>";
```

These accomplish the same thing.

This principle is the same, BTW, if your code looks like this:

```
$results = some_mysql_query;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ...
        echo $row['RecordNumber'];
```

Also, in case you're not already aware of how this will work, your recordInfo.php will receive its information in the `$_GET` array; specifically, it will refer to the RecordNumber as `$_GET['RecordNumber']`.

Comment: I am missing something: probably syntax; here is what i have.  It is not filling in anything to pass. When hovering over the link, it shows the the following at the end of the url:     /record_info.php?record=       Here is the relevant code:

Comment: while($employee= mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . "<a href='record_info.php?record='" . $employee['call_id'] . "'>" . $employee['call_id'] . "</a>";
            echo "<td>" . $employee['call_state'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $employee['enter_date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $employee['employee'] . "</td>";  
            echo "<td>" . $employee['call_reason'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }//end while

Comment: I could not seem to duplicate your code and get it to work.  This may not be the best option, but it is doing what I need:                $call_id = $employee['call_id'];
            $customer = $employee['customer_name'];
            echo "<td>" . "<a href='view_record.php?call_id=$call_id'>$customer</a>" . "</td>";

Comment: Is PHP letting you use the variables within the echoed string (ie, within the quotation marks) without wrapping them in curly brackets ({$call_id})? That surprises me, but okay, cool! What you're doing is completely fine - what you should be able to do, alternatively, is this:  `echo "<td>" . "<a href='view_record.php?call_id={$employee['call_id']}'>{$employee['customer_name']}</a>" . "</td>";`

Comment: Also, as a complete aside, I'd suggest looking into PDO, rather than using the `mysql_whatever()` functions - it's not very difficult once you get into a little bit, and it's much more secure with regard to SQL injection, without having to mess around with `mysql_real_escape_string()` and so on.